# page.response - can't set it in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I generate a PDF document inside a helper method. the helper method returns a HttpResponse object, which is the response containing the generated PDF. But I can't change the page.response to the one the method returned. How shuld I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Get the text from the underlying HTMLTextWriter for your PDF HTTPResponse object and write it to the current one using the [Response.OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) object.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data out of the response object that you get from the method, and send it into the response object that is handling the response.

I don't see the reason for the method to return a response object; as it can't be used as a response to anything it seems pointless.